# Resuming persistent sessions while switching to a different mosquitto broker

Tags: session, mqtt, mosquitto, persistent

Can anyone tell me how I can resume persistent session on a different broker while I am switching brokers for load balancing in mosquitto. I am really confused and can't find a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you don't.

All the persistent session information is held in the broker and mosquitto has no way to share that information between instances

Comment: Even after creating a cluster, there's no way I can transfer the session?. I am writing my thesis and this is a module I wanted to implement. Now I am really confused if I came down the right path or not. You have written the code of mosquito, would you suggest that I should change my goal as there's no way I will be able to transfer the session.

Comment: So your original question was "How do I implement my thesis?"

Comment: Also there is no concept of a cluster with mosquitto, just a collection of bridged brokers

Comment: " Well, I am sorry if my statements led to that interpretation. This was NOT my question. Being a PhD student, I wanted to contribute something to this area. I have been working very hard and have no one for supervision whatsoever. That is why I consorted to this platform for help as a last resort. Thank you so much for the help and support!" *for guidance as a last resort, since I lost faith in what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Stack Overflow really isn't the right place to ask an open source project if they would accept a large new feature. What you are describing would be a **major** change to the code base. Mosquitto project has an active developer mailing list.